# string to json format powershell

Tags: json, string, powershell

Hey guys I have a singular string output which I need to convert in JSON:

```
Policy Name: Default_US1 Id: abc123 Buckets: bucket1,bothplaces
Policy Name: Default_CH1 Id: def456 Buckets: support,ch1,ch2
Policy Name: Default_NY2 Id: ghi789 Buckets: demo,bucket1,test1,test
```

How SHOULD it look like in JSON format?

```
[ 
{"Policy Name": "Default_US1"}, {"Id": "abc123"}, {"Buckets":[ "bucket1","bothplaces"]}
{"Policy Name": "Default_CH1"}, {"Id": "def456"}, {"Buckets":[ "support","ch1","ch2"]}
{"Policy Name": "Default_NY2"}, {"Id": "ghi789"}, {"Buckets":[ "demo","bucket1","test1","test"]}
]
```

above is my current attempt... but other than not working.. I know instinctively it's missing something/s... but I cant figure out what and how to remedy it

Directions on how to do it in Powershell would be a plus, but not necessary

I keep trying but messing up, since I know the best test is making Convertfrom-json show me normal output.

I do not care much how it ends up looking at the end, I just wish to extract all that data, with JSON being the format of choice, any VALID JSON result I can work with and manipulate....but first i need a valid JSON conversion

Comment: We can't tell you what your JSON should look like - whatever system is consuming that JSON will tell you what the JSON must look like (or have I misunderstood your question?)

Comment: no system is consuming it, it's just a bad reporting output from an API, for which I am trying to extract data from to make usable

Comment: A system is still consuming it (even if, as in your case, that "system" is a human) - we can't tell you what output format makes most sense as the only person who can decide that is you (in co-ordination with the person who will be reading this JSON, which may be yourself as well). It's a business problem, not a technical problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so you were correct - your current JSON format is ghastly! The mistake you are making is treating each little bit of data as a separate object when there appears to be a natural hierarchy in your data model.

The following structure more naturally fits your data model. However, this is purely based on a cursory examination of the input data you have posted - I know nothing about the data model itself.

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Default_US1",
        "Id": "abc123",
        "Buckets": [
            "bucket1",
            "bothplaces"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Default_CH1",
        "Id": "def456",
        "Buckets": [
            "support",
            "ch1",
            "ch2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Default_NY2",
        "Id": "ghi789",
        "Buckets": [
            "demo",
            "bucket1",
            "test1",
            "test2"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: thank you very much... sigh... i knew i was messing up something very obvious